# postgres group by category but require 1 of each value

Tags: postgresql

## Edit

i've created a db fiddle to show the current db schema

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vwnrjuBHKYYDsXr3kAAvWE/1

I'm struggling with grouping sets unique values in a gift table.
There are 4 gifts per category which I want to count as 1 set. Kind of like a loyalty card where the set is complete when you have all 4 of the gifts.

I want to query how many sets each user has of each category.

So the source table looks like (simplified):

| row | user_id | gift_id | gift_category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1 | perfume |
| 2 | 123 | 2 | perfume |
| 3 | 123 | 3 | perfume |
| 4 | 123 | 4 | perfume |
| 5 | 123 | 1 | perfume |
| 6 | 123 | 2 | perfume |
| 7 | 123 | 4 | perfume |
| 8 | 123 | 6 | drink |

desired outcome should be:

| user_id | gift_category | set_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | perfume | 1 |

because category drink doesn't have all 4 gifts (based on 4 unique gift_id's) this one doesn't count. Also because the user misses 1 perfume (gift_id 3) of the second set this also doesn't count.

Is there a way to to query the desired outcome?

*EDIT

- should have at least one of each gift_id 1,2,3,4 for perfume and 5,6,7,8 for drinks to have 1 set.

the gift table looks like this (denormalized version):

| gift_id | gift_category | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | perfume | chanel |
| 2 | perfume | olly |
| 3 | perfume | christine |
| 4 | perfume | lacoste |
| 5 | drink | beer |
| 6 | drink | wine |
| 7 | drink | vodka |
| 8 | drink | rum |

so,to have 1 set of each, you have to have 1 gift id in each category

Comment: But perfume itself is missing `gift_id` 6, so why is it a match here?

Comment: is it the specific `gift_id`, so having at least 1 or each of 1,2,3,4, or is it based only on having a count of 4 or more?

Comment: @ChrisSchaller 1 of each, see my updated question

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen gift_id 6 is from category drink. I've updated with a gift table to clarify

Comment: Do you have a table for gift categories?

Comment: @ChrisSchaller yes, I just denormalized it here above to simplify. So gift_category above actually is gift_category_id. I'll try and make a dbfiddle if you like

Comment: I hope you'll be able to transpose the solution, but it is useful to know if the giftcategory_id only available on the `gift` table or if you have lifted it to the _Sale_ table as well.

Comment: It is not often that _denormalizing_ makes things _simpler_ in SQL. But I found a way

Answer (score 0):

We need to compute a list of all the possible matches between `Users` and `Gifts` then outer join on the *Sale* table (`User_Gifts`).

Then `GROUP BY` the `gift_category` and but only return the groups that do not have any missing *Sales*

```
SELECT Users.user_id, gifts.gift_category_id, gift_categories.name as gift_category
FROM Users
CROSS JOIN Gifts
INNER JOIN gift_categories ON Gifts.gift_category_id = gift_categories.gift_category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_gifts ON user_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id and user_gifts.user_id = Users.user_id
GROUP BY Users.user_id, gifts.gift_category_id, gift_categories.name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN user_gifts.gift_Id IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Have a look at this fiddle for proof: https://www.db-https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vwnrjuBHKYYDsXr3kAAvWE/2

| user_id | gift_category_id | gift_category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | perfume |

> **NOTE:**
> In the [Fiddle](https://www.db-https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vwnrjuBHKYYDsXr3kAAvWE/2), there was no `Users` table, so I used a CTE to construct one out of the unique `user_id` in the `user_gifts` table data.

---

Step 1, Construct the matrix of all options and those that have been taken, we accept duplicates here:

```
SELECT Users.user_id
     , Gifts.*
     , gift_categories.name as gift_category
     , user_gifts.*
FROM Users
CROSS JOIN Gifts
INNER JOIN gift_categories ON Gifts.gift_category_id = gift_categories.gift_category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_gifts ON user_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id and user_gifts.user_id = Users.user_id
```

| user_id | gift_id | name | gift_category_id | name | user_gift_id | gift_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | chanel | 1 | perfume | 1 | 1 | 123 |
| 123 | 1 | chanel | 1 | perfume | 5 | 1 | 123 |
| 123 | 2 | olly | 1 | perfume | 6 | 2 | 123 |
| 123 | 2 | olly | 1 | perfume | 2 | 2 | 123 |
| 123 | 3 | christine | 1 | perfume | 3 | 3 | 123 |
| 123 | 4 | lacoste | 1 | perfume | 4 | 4 | 123 |
| 123 | 4 | lacoste | 1 | perfume | 7 | 4 | 123 |
| 123 | 5 | beer | 2 | drinks | null | null | null |
| 123 | 6 | wine | 2 | drinks | 8 | 6 | 123 |
| 123 | 7 | vodka | 2 | drinks | null | null | null |
| 123 | 8 | rum | 2 | drinks | null | null | null |

Step 2: Group the results and Count the zeros and non-zeros (we only need the zeros but its helpful to see that it works)

```
SELECT Users.user_id, gifts.gift_category_id, gift_categories.name as gift_category
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN user_gifts.gift_Id IS NULL THEN 1 END) as MissingGifts
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN user_gifts.gift_Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) as SoldGifts
FROM Users
CROSS JOIN Gifts
INNER JOIN gift_categories ON Gifts.gift_category_id = gift_categories.gift_category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_gifts ON user_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id and user_gifts.user_id = Users.user_id
GROUP BY Users.user_id, gifts.gift_category_id, gift_categories.name
```

| user_id | gift_category_id | gift_category | missinggifts | soldgifts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | perfume | 0 | 7 |
| 123 | 2 | drinks | 3 | 0 |

Step 3: Use `HAVING` to ensure we only select the rows that have *Zero*, `0`s, or in this set, *zero* `missinggifts`

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN user_gifts.gift_Id IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I've added a dbfiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vwnrjuBHKYYDsXr3kAAvWE/1 to clarify. So I think the Sale table you used is the same as user_gifts as in the fiddle. I don't see a set count (4 gifts per category) in your answer?

Comment: I rewrote the solution, this is much more SQL'ish than my first attempt. And yes I prefer to name my tables after the type of relationship or business concept that they represent, `user_gifts` explains the primary relationship, but not what the underlying concept is in the business domain. ;)